# displaying dates in strust2 datetimepicker

Tags: date, datetime, struts2, struts2-interceptors

when I disabled all days `(2013-11-15(yyyy-MM-dd))` before this and after this`(2013-12-02(yyyy-MM-dd))` in struts2 datetimepicker , I am getting output for all enable days in one month, that means 01,02 dates in December month also I am getting in November.
the code for this is,

```
sx:datetimepicker name="deliverydate" label="Delivery Date" startDate="%{'2013-11-15'}" endDate="%{'2013-12-02'}" value="%{'today'}"
         displayFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" adjustWeeks="5" id="deliverydate"
```

output is in calender,

```
          10 11 12 13 14 15 16
          17 18 19 20 21 22 23
          24 25 26 27 28 29 30
           1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
           8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

in above before 15 ,after 2 are disabled dates, and I am getting all dates in November month only,I want to display November month must end with 30 and remaining enable days in next month.
How to display in next month?

Comment: do you want to see the dates of Nov and Dec when you select a date in Nov?